# Need help getting first 2 rows of csv file with this format

Tags: python-2.7, csv, formatting

I am trying to print out the first 2 rows of my `csv` file with this format. I have tried different things, but keep getting errors.

The code below currently works great for formatting the output of the entire `csv` file, but now I need to just grab the first two rows. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have looked everywhere for the answer on this site, some come close, but not getting what I want.

I am new to `python` and also new to using csv files. Thanks in advance.

```
f1 = open("csvfile.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f1)
for row in csv_f:
print '{:<13}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^8}'.format(*row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import csv

with open("csvfile.csv") as f1:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f1)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_f):
        print '{:<13}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^8}'.format(*row)
        if i >= 1:
            break
```

Comment: You are awesome! Works beautifully!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, The Stackoverflow way to show it is to mark it as accepted and also upvote it.

Comment: I would but, im new here and I dont have the rep to do it. Thank you for your time. Thank you again.

Comment: @KaliBerry on your own questions, I think you should always be able to vote on the answers and mark an answer as accepted.  Cheers.